# How can I build a specific branch of Monero?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, build

I would like to build a specific branch of Monero, and I would like help setting it up to build on Debian. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

**Start by opening a terminal and installing all the dependencies:**

`sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev && cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake . && sudo make && sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libboost-all-dev libssl-dev  libzmq3-dev libunbound-dev libsodium-dev`

**cd to the directory you want to download the files to.** For example, if you want to go to the home directory (recommended for beginners), use `cd ~`.

**Clone the repository:**

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/monero-project/monero`

^ if you are using a branch from another contributor, then the URL will be different. Adjust accordingly.

`cd monero && git submodule init && git submodule update`

(Replace `monero` with `bitmonero` if this doesn't work)

**Check out the desired branch.** Replace `<branch>` with the name of the branch:

`git checkout <branch>`

**You can finally build the binaries.** Replace `<t>` with the number of cores your CPU has.

`make -j <t>` (eg: `make -j 2`)

Answer (score 1):

A present date solution that is more compact (installs the submodules and checks out the branch automatically when cloning) is:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential cmake pkg-config libboost-all-dev libssl-dev libzmq3-dev libunbound-dev libsodium-dev libunwind8-dev liblzma-dev libreadline6-dev libldns-dev libexpat1-dev doxygen graphviz libpgm-dev`

`cd ~ && git clone --recursive https://github.com/monero-project/monero --branch <branch name> && cd monero && make -j2`